# KVM VM dhcp while configured a static IP in XML

Tags: kvm, libvirt

I'm trying to workaround a DHCP issue by configuring my guest VM to use DHCP (to avoid having to configure it manually with a static IP) but defining a static IP in the XML.

This would enable setting an IP upon creation while not requiring configuring the virtual machines operating system to a static IP (making it sort of "independent").

I should point out:

- Guests are Windows/Linux mixed
- Must use a bridge setup (not NAT)

Is this a reasonable solution? any recommendations to the actual XML markup of the guest?

Answer (score 1):

When saying static ip configuration instead of DHCP, it's not a libvirt thing but a configuration of guest OS. refer to this [maillist](http://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2009-February/msg00413.html) for example.

So you can make it via a custom DHCP server that listens on your bridge network instead of default NAT. it only assigns specific ips to specific mac addresses. It's very easy to make it via `dnsmasq`.

If you do want to exclude any DHCP broadcast in your bridge network, think about bootstrap processes inside your guest OS. The [config drive](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/datasources.html#config-drive) is a good choice where it allows you creating a disk file and attach to the VM, then the `cloud-init` daemon on guest OS will pick it up to replace network configuration. But it's just too many if you just want static ips.